# Oclint show error always -bash: path/to/xctool.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, file, directory, oclint

I am using Oclint to generate code review report of application. for this I have used below link 
http://oclint.org

I am using Xctool in the oclint. for installing xctool I have used this document:
http://docs.oclint.org/en/stable/guide/xctool.html

but whenever I write any thing by the help of path/to/xctool.sh terminal is showing the error 
for ex 
path/to/xctool.sh -help

Error : 
-bash: path/to/xctool.sh: No such file or directory

Can any one help me I need to generate the code review report of my application but it is taking tooo much time of me and nothing is working.

Thanks